# How pandas can add search for "?" with str.contains

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas `str.contains` to extent the search for multiple patterns  including `"?"` using `"|"` operator which runs and results correct.

I have few points which i would like to know from expert opinions as follows.

1. Is there a better way to use `str.contains` like putting all the
   search patterns into a variable like below, i know that's doable but would like to know if its better way using this?

   `patt = "AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|\?"`
2. As you may see i've `*` appearing on some of the hostnames, can those be removed using pandas ie for example `test-centos71*`

### Code snippet:

```
$ cat getsurvey.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##################### END OF THE Display Settings ###################

col_names = ['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'CPU Model', 'CDN Version', 'OS Version', 'Kernel Version', 'LDAP Profile']
#df1 = pd.read_csv('host.txt-Org', delimiter = "\t", usecols=col_names, encoding='cp1252', low_memory=False)
df1 = pd.read_csv('host.txt-Org', delimiter = "\t", usecols=col_names, encoding='cp1252',  dtype='unicode')
df2 = df1[df1['OS Version'].str.contains("AIX|CentOS|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|\?",  na=False)][['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']]
print(df2)
```

### Result:

```
$ ./getsurvey.py 
                               Hostname        IP Address              Aux Site                 OS Version
5266                     test-centos71*            NaN                    NaN                          ?
9824                      test-centos72     192.1.1.126                  test                          ?
9886                      test-centos73     192.1.1.36                   test                          ?
11457                    test-centos74*     192.1.1.107                  test                          ?
12485                    test-centos75*     192.1.11.85                  test                          ?
13187                         foreman01     192.1.1.31                   test                          ?
```

### RAW DATA:

```
Hostname    IP Address  Aux Site    CPU Model             CDN Version   OS Version  Kernel Version              LDAP Profile
test-centos71*  NaN         NaN      1x 2.90 GHz Xeon E5-4617    f06.01         RHEL 5.5    2.6.18-194.el5               STD
test-centos72   192.1.1.126 US DC        1x 3.00 GHz Xeon E5-2690    f03.00         RHEL 6.5    2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_6    STD
test-centos76*  NaN         NaN      1x 2.90 GHz Xeon E5-4617    f06.01         RHEL 5.5    2.6.18-194.el5               STD
```

appreciate your time and help in advanced.

### Edit:

Got the solution for my second question as i understand with replace.. this works fine, just open to have other opinions ..

```
df2['Hostname'] = df2['Hostname'].str.replace("*", "")
```

Comment: would like show the data ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben, Just provided few lines of raw data which mimics to the real data.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can also try with replace() and re.sub():

```
df2['Hostname'] = df2['Hostname'].replace('\*', '')
```

or,

```
import re
df2['Hostname'] = df2['Hostname'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\*', '', x))
```

Comment: Loochie, +1 & thnx for giving a thought around, yes `replace` i have already tried that working fine, importing `re` looks little overkill here.